# Which machine or domain does mimikatz sekurlsa loggedon return logged on users from?

Tags: active-directory

The mimikatz docu says "SEKURLSA::LogonPasswords – lists all available provider credentials. This usually shows recently logged on user and computer credentials."

Where are these users logged on to? The current Active Directory domain, to which the machine I use to run mimikatz is connected?

Answer (score 0):

#### Where are these users logged on to?

> The `logonpasswords` command extracts a user ID and password for
> currently logged-in and recently logged-in users of the target system.
>
> The `sekurlsa` module includes other commands to extract Kerberos
> credentials and encryption keys, and it can even perform a
> pass-the-hash attack using the credentials `Mimikatz` extracts.

Source: [Mimikatz tutorial: How it hacks Windows passwords, credentials | TechTarget](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/tutorial/Mimikatz-tutorial-How-it-hacks-Windows-passwords-credentials)

Comment: yes exactly, and where are these users logged in? In the machine from which I'm running mimikatz?

Comment: "the target system"